# DropDownList Error in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

After adding the class to the html.dropdownlist am facing the below error.

**Error:**'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

```
<li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuildType)
                    @Html.DropDownList("BuildType", new { @class = "BuildType" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BuildType)
                </li>
                <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuildMode)
                    @Html.DropDownList("BuildMode", new { @class = "BuildMode" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BuildMode) </li>
                <li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BuildType, (SelectList)Viewbag.YourSelectList, "Select Build type", new { @class = "BuildType" })
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BuildType, Model.YourSelectList, "Select Build type", new { @class = "BuildType" })
```

When you use `@Html.DropDownList`, you specify a name for the dropdownlist... but you are missing the SelectList itself.  I think that out of the box, the helper will try to use the name of the DropDownList (in your case "BuildType") to search in the ViewData collection for the SelectList.

When you use a `@Html.DropDownListFor` you don't use a name, but a lamda expression `m => m.BuildType` that will help you in same cases to not have harcoded names.

Your `SelectList` (the second parameter) can be grabbed from `Viewbag` or from a property in your `Model`.

Answer (score 2):

Where are your list options? You need to provide a list of options via an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` object (see [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)).

So your model would have something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuildModeOptions { get; set; }
```

And your view would pass the list into the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BuildMode", Model.BuildModeOptions, new { @class = "BuildType" })
```

Or, since you're using the type-safe `For` versions on your other helpers, use `DropDownListFor` on this one as well:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BuildMode, Model.BuildModeOptions, new { @class = "BuildType" })
```

But keep in mind, Model.BuildMode is your selected value -- Model.BuildModeOptions is for your dropdown options.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter should be the list of items you want to show in the dropdown.

so It will look like :

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor("BuildType", m.yourListofItems, new { @class = "BuildType" })
```